# Approximating Magnitude of Solutions

Tags: equation-solving, approximation

I was recently lecturing on the hierarchy of functions in a calculus class. Discussing the fact that eventually any exponential growth function will overcome any polynomial. As an example, I tried asking Mathematica the following:`NSolve[q^800 + 4000000 == (1000001/1000000)^q, q, Reals]` and it completely choked.

Honestly, I'm only interested in the order of magnitude of the answer, so that I can say, "The exponential doesn't exceed the polynomial until you input ???-digit numbers, but eventually it does happen."

How can I get Mathematica to solve this just to an order of magnitude, i.e. how do I get Mathematica to just provide a really gross estimate?

Comment: Maybe take a `Log` of both sides and use `FindRoot`? Maybe plot the function out near where you think the crossing is and use that as an estimate for `FindRoot`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following up on my comment, here's something that works, thought not automatically. Taking advantage of the monotonicity of the logarithm, we do

```
Table[
  Plot[{Log[q^800 + 4000000], q Log[1000001/1000000]}, {q, 10^k, 10^(k + 1)}]
  , {k, 7, 10}
]~Partition~2 // Grid
```

resulting in

[image]

It looks like `q` is about 20 billion, and so

```
FindRoot[Log[q^800 + 4000000] == Log[(1000001/1000000)^q], {q, 2*10^10.}]
(* {q -> 1.89313*10^10} *)
```

---

Alternatively, still take the logarithms (to avoid overflow issues, I think), but do a `LogLinearPlot`:

```
LogLinearPlot[{Log[q^800 + 4000000], q Log[(1000001/1000000)]}, {q, 0.1, 10^12}]
```

resulting in

[image]

Then approximate the crossing by eye, and either you're done or you feed it `FindRoot` as above.